# Error : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'source')

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, axios

I'm using WordPress API in my react native app. Everything is working fine except my single post screen. I'm requesting post data, updating state, and rendering data from the state. My app was crashing after going on this screen. I spend hours and I've found out what's the problem however don't how to fix it.

My Screen Code -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from "react-native";
import HTMLView from "react-native-htmlview";
import globalStyles from "../constant/globalStyle";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import { Colors } from "../constant/colors";

const PostDetail = ({ route }) => {
  const { postId } = route.params;
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({});
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [source, setSource] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(
          `https://bachrasouthpanchayat.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${postId}?embed=true`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          setPostData(response.data);
          setSource(response.data.content.rendered);
          setLoaded(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error, error.message));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={{
        ...globalStyles.container,
        backgroundColor: Colors.BACKGROUND_SCREEN,
      }}
    >
      {loaded ? (
        <>
          <Image
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 250,
            }}
            source={{ uri: postData.jetpack_featured_media_url }}
            resizeMode="cover"
          />
          <Text style={globalStyles.primaryHeading}>
            {postData.title.rendered}
          </Text>
          <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 18 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                alignItems: "center",
                marginBottom: 10,
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...globalStyles.date,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: "700",
                }}
              >
                {moment(postData.date).format("LL")}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <HTMLView
              stylesheet={{
                p: { fontSize: 20, color: "white", textAlign: "justify" },
                h1: {
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: 32,
                },
                h2: {
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: 28,
                },
                figure: {
                  backgroundColor: "red",
                  width: "100% !important",
                  height: "100% !important",
                },
                img: {
                  width: "100% !important",
                  backgroundColor: "green",
                },
              }}
              value={source}
              imagesMaxWidth={width}
            />
          </View>
        </>
      ) : (
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          <ActivityIndicator size={60} color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN} />
        </View>
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default PostDetail;
```

I've used a bunch of console log statements and found out that "when useEffect runs the request is sent to API but it didn't stay on that line of code to receive a response, instead remaining lines of codes are executed and that's why I was getting the undefined error". However, the state gets updated after some time but I still get the error.

I have used async & await but don't know why all those remaining lines of codes ran before getting a response.

Answer (score 3):

When this page is rendered for the first time, your **postData** is an empty object:

```
const [postData, setPostData] = useState({});
```

and at this point of time you try to access it's children (but it doesn't have them yet):

```
      <Text style={globalStyles.primaryHeading}>
        {postData.title.rendered} // here you access the empty object
      </Text>
```

Then the **useEffect** is called which populates that postData

**The solution (just add the question mark after postData.title?.rendered):**

```
     <Text style={globalStyles.primaryHeading}>
        {postData.title?.rendered}
      </Text>
```

The better solution is to show loading until you have not fetched the component:

```
if(postData.title?.rendered) 
 return <ActivityIndicator size={24} color={"#424242"} />

return (
    <ScrollView
      style={{
        ...globalStyles.container,
        backgroundColor: Colors.BACKGROUND_SCREEN,
      }}
    >
      {loaded ? (
        <>
          <Image
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 250,
            }}
            source={{ uri: postData.jetpack_featured_media_url }}
            resizeMode="cover"
          />
          <Text style={globalStyles.primaryHeading}>
            {postData.title.rendered}
          </Text>
          <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 18 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                alignItems: "center",
                marginBottom: 10,
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...globalStyles.date,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: "700",
                }}
              >
                {moment(postData.date).format("LL")}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <HTMLView
              stylesheet={{
                p: { fontSize: 20, color: "white", textAlign: "justify" },
                h1: {
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: 32,
                },
                h2: {
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: 28,
                },
                figure: {
                  backgroundColor: "red",
                  width: "100% !important",
                  height: "100% !important",
                },
                img: {
                  width: "100% !important",
                  backgroundColor: "green",
                },
              }}
              value={source}
              imagesMaxWidth={width}
            />
          </View>
        </>
      ) : (
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          <ActivityIndicator size={60} color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN} />
        </View>
      )}
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What to do here (in source={{ uri: postData.jetpack_featured_media_url }}
) ? -
<Image
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 250,
            }}
            source={{ uri: postData.jetpack_featured_media_url }}
            resizeMode="cover"
          />

Comment: {postData?.jetpack_featured_media_url ? <Image
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 250,
            }}
            source={{ uri: postData.jetpack_featured_media_url }}
            resizeMode="cover"
          /> : null}

Comment: If there is no postData.jetpack_featured_media_url return null, otherwise display the image with that URI

Comment: The same for date: {postData.date ? <Text
                style={{
                  ...globalStyles.date,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: "700",
                }}
              >
                {moment(postData.date).format("LL")}
              </Text> : null}

Comment: postData?.date OR postData.date ? 

Comment: Why would it try to render empty postData at all since `loaded` is false until the axios call returns.

Comment: It doesn't matter at this level, since postData is an empty object hence the date is undefined. The problem arises when you try to access one more level, for example postData.date.something, since date is undefined you cannot access something property which causes your error: Error : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'postData.date.something'). In this case you want to use question mark, so you tell the compiler you are aware of that fact that it can be empty and you wan't to access the property which may not exist

Comment: ohh.... everything is working fine but I'm trapped with <HTMLView />